# AngularJS POSTing 2D array

Tags: c#, angularjs

angular http post:

```
    $http({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        url: "myCSharpMethod", 
        method: "POST",
        data: myData,    // this is my 2D array ( myData[[],[]] )
        traditional: true
    })
      .success(function(response){
            console.log(response)};
```

my c# controller:

```
 public string myCSharpMethod(string[][] myData){
    return myData[0][0];
    }
```

My issues is that the console log from the post.success is a null exception error. Please help.

Comment: It's not clear how the request goes from the POST request you're making to the C# function. Are you using an application server? ASP.NET? Please add more context and relevant code to your question, so we can understand better what is the problem

Comment: yes, i'm using asp.net

Comment: Can you please print out the raw value of `myData`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `JSON.stringify` in your post:

```
$http({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    url: "myCSharpMethod", 
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(myData),    // this is my 2D array ( myData[[],[]] )
    traditional: true
})
```

Also it is always a good idea to create a view model and send it rather than just the array itself:

```
public class MyViewModel
{    
    public string[][] TableData { get; set; }
}
```

And your method signature will change to:

```
public string myCSharpMethod([FromBody] MyViewModel myData){
    return myData.TableData[0][0];
}
```

Comment: $http will JSON.stringify internally by default. The `traditional` part is strange though